# create a star schema database from an xml file

Tags: sql-server, xml, import, schema

Is it possible to create a Star Schema Database from data available in an XML file or a text file?

Your valuable inputs appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Sam.

Answer (score 0):

It's a very vague question, but you can pretty much describe anything logical with an XML file. XML is "extensible", so you can make it describe nearly any set of data in any form as long as there is consistency.

Comment: I am new to the Star Schema concept, so would like to know if one needs to have multiple tables in order to create a Star Schema Database or is just one table sufficient to create one?

Comment: Star schema means you have one "fact" table, with all the relational tables that related to it. Fact tables are usually data at the very lowest level of granularity possible. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema

Answer (score 0):

I've done both.  I wrote a some JavaScripts that parse files and creates records in an Oracle database.  One script processed the Tyco2 data from a formated text file.  I've only done two of the 20 text files (250,000 stars) because of the size and I'm doing this on my laptop.  A similar file created a table for the Hipparcos data (118,000 stars).  The other I just finished processed the data from a file called "Stars - 2300+6000-2.xml."  That file contained some stars with names and I created a table with the named stars that matched the Hipparcos stars.  Alas only 92 of them showed up.

For xml, I used the Microsoft.XMLDOM interface and to add the data to Oracle, I used ADODB.Connection.  The xml also used ADODB.Recordset because I had to run queries against the Hipparcos table to find the Hipparcos number (where there was a match) matching a star in the xml file.

If that is what your looking for, let me know and I can send the JavaScripts.

Frank Perry, MSEE

Comment: Hi Frank, it sounds like you are talking about 'generic' scripts to turn XML files into multiple star schemas? If you are, I would be interested as I have a similar need to the person posting the original question